# Opera and ie cache <p class="hide">, so javascript doesn' work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, opera

sorry my question is dumb.

I have a simple css file with class hide, that makes an element hidden (wow!). I use simple javascript to unhide element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var a = $("p.hide");
    a.removeClass("hide")
});
```

It works in Firefox, Chrome, but in Opera and IE I should manualy reload page to see an effect.

Can somebody tell me where to read how to fo it right?

Comment: Works for me in IE6/7 and Opera 10.

Comment: Do you use display: none or visibility: hidden ?

Because if you use display: none, it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Try a click event:

```
$('#element-that-shows-hidden-p').click(function () { 
  $('p.hide').removeClass('hide'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like perhaps the element is not redrawn correctly after the class change? It would help to have the URL of the page where you see this problem as redraw issues are usually entirely dependent on surrounding code and other CSS on the page.